# Developing android on android

Tags: android

Is there currently a way of developing android apps on an android phone? In other words, write, compile, install and run regular android java on the phone without using a pc? If not, what would make it possible, if at all? (would rooting be necessary? Or an android emulator compiled for android?)

Answer (score 7):

[Android-IDE (AIDE)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui) is the first application which allows you to develop another android application in mobile device.

- AIDE (Android IDE) allows you to develop an Android project in any android based mobile phone.You don’t need any PC or any editor not even eclipse.
- The main aim of AIDE is Self-contained mobile developed platform.

You can look for [Meme IDE 1.14 for Windows Mobile and Android](http://www.sdtimes.com/MEME_IDE_1_14_FOR_WINDOWS_MOBILE_AND_ANDROID_FULL_VERSION_RELEASED/By_SD_TIMES_NEWSWIRE/36059), check the detail on the link specified..

Ref:
 [Android-IDE (AIDE)](http://gtu-mca.weebly.com/aide-android-ide-download-without-eclipse.html)
[Develop Android apps from within Android using AIDE (video)](http://www.engadget.com/2012/03/07/develop-android-using-aide-video/)

Comment: I think that's not the first, (IIRC) [terminal-ide](http://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/) was available sooner.

Comment: AIDE is absolutely the best Android-on-Android development environment - it also comes with built-in GIT support.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with AIDE, haven't tried it personally though.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui